# Pass the value in XML before post using SOAP

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, soap

i get a xml that i need to post via SOAP request. i want to create serialization structure for the XML so that i can pass the value easily in the xml before post it.

```
    <SOAP:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' >
    <SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{78521NMF-878F-459N-88514-543BCDE4444}' >
        <m:SaveOrder
            xmlns:m = 'http://www.Ncdc.com/schemas/' >
            <Order UserID = '1' Notes = 'Pick up from ME between 10 am- 1 pm and deliver straight.' 
CustomerID = '85211'  OrderDate = '08/01/2017' >
                <Customer />
                <Stops >
                    <Stop Sequence = '1' StopType = 'P' Note = ''  >
                        <OrderStopPieces >
                            <OrderStopPiece Sequence = '1' PieceAction = 'P' />
                        </OrderStopPieces >
                    </Stop >
                    <Stop Sequence = '2' StopType = 'D' Note = ''  >
                        <OrderStopPieces >
                            <OrderStopPiece Sequence = '1' PieceAction = 'D' />
                        </OrderStopPieces >
                    </Stop >
                </Stops >
                <Jobs >
                    <Job Sequence = '1' />
                </Jobs >
                <Pieces >
                    <Piece Sequence = '1' Pieces = '1' Weight = ''  />
                </Pieces >
            </Order >
        </m:SaveOrder >
    </SOAP:Body >
</SOAP:Envelope >
```

Thanks for your suggestion and time